# How to draw image/bmp from HTTP API to HTML canvas in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, http, canvas

Working entirely on the client side, I intend to use an HTTP service that responds to a POST request by sending a BMP file with the response type set to `image/bmp`.

How can I draw this image to an HTML canvas object using JavaScirpt?

Here's a piece of code that results in a gibberish image (due to an incorrect processing of raw binary data?):

```
 function refresh() {
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open('POST', 'imgview');
     request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     request.setRequestHeader('Response-Type', 'image/bmp');
     request.onload = function(event) {
         if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
             var blob = new Blob([request.response], {type: 'image/bmp'});
             var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
             var image = new Image;
             image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
             image.onload = function() {
                 console.log(image.width)
                 document.body.appendChild(image);
                 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                 context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
             }
             image.src = imageURL;
         } else {
             // [...]
         }
     };

// [...]
request.send(requestText);
```

Comment: Do you get an error? You may need to set the image cross origin access to anonymous. `image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`

Comment: That was missing, thank you, but this change alone does not solve the problem. I revised the question accordingly. The image still has width 0.

Comment: And what if you just append the image using `document.body.appendChild(image)`? Just to see if the image is loaded at all.

Comment: Don't you need an `image.onload` to make sure the image has loaded before you draw to canvas

Comment: @Kokodoko: Thanks for the advice! An image is added to the document, but it looks nothing like the image I expect. Might this be a difficulty converting the raw binary HTTP response to some other encoding?

Comment: @Helder Sepulveda: You are right. I have revised the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't have enough information to prove if this will help, but some times those ajax'd in images come with a header for the data, like first 15 bytes ish, and you need to trim that off before turning it into a blob.

Comment: I changed the server now such that it sends the binary data in base64 encoding. I thought, however, that this was not necessary for HTTP. Am I wrong?